# Re-open an NSWindow after it has been closed?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, foundation, nswindowcontroller

I have a subclass of an `NSWindowController` called `UpgradeWindowController`.

So far this works for the first click; the window launches. However if you close that window, and click the button again to show upgrade window, nothing happens.

```
- (IBAction)showUpgradeWindow:(id)sender {
    if (!self.upgradeController){
        self.upgradeController = [[UpgradeWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"UpgradeWindow"];
    }
    [self.upgradeController showWindow:self];
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was the XIB. The file's owner needed to be connected to the Window.

Answer (score 0):

Give you a suggestion, the window can be objects stored in a variable or array, although this is closed, but is actually hidden, the next time we need to use it, can go to check the window if the object is loaded, if loaded to call and display it. This can be more interesting and convenient.